# Reading and Writing to a file in C

Tags: c

I am slowly learning C, but not very well. I have been reading over the countless topics and questions on reading and writing, but I have yet to be able to find anything that makes this all click for me.

I was given the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 100

struct YouTubeVideo { 
char video_name[1024];      // YouTube video name
int ranking;                // Number of viewer hits
char url[1024];             // YouTube URL
};

struct YouTubeVideo Collection[MAX];

int tail = 0;

//-- Forward Declaration --// 
void printall();
void insertion();
void branching(char option);
void menu(); 


int main()
{
char ch; 

// TODO: Add code to load save data from file

printf("\n\nWelcome to CSE240: YouTube Classic Hits\n");

do {
     menu();
     fflush(stdin);           // Flush the standard input buffer 
     ch = tolower(getchar()); // read a char, convert to lower case
     branching(ch);
} while (ch != 'q');

return 0; 
}

void menu()
{
printf("\nMenu Options\n");
printf("------------------------------------------------------\n");
printf("i: Insert a new favorite\n");
printf("p: Review your list\n"); 
printf("q: Save and quit\n");
printf("\n\nPlease enter a choice (i, p, or q) ---> "); 
}

void branching(char option)
{
switch(option)
{
    case 'i':
        insertion();
    break;

    case 'p':
        printall();
    break;

    case 'q':
        // TODO: Add code to save data into a file
    break;

    default:
        printf("\nError: Invalid Input.  Please try again..."); 
    break;
}
}

void insertion()
{
if(tail < MAX)
{
    printf("\nWhat is the name of the video? (No spaces characters allowed)\n");
    scanf("%s", Collection[tail].video_name);

    printf("\nHow many viewer hits does this video have?\n");
    scanf("%d", &Collection[tail].ranking);

    printf("\nPlease enter the URL: ");
    scanf("%s", &Collection[tail].url);

    tail++;
}
else
{
    printf("\nERROR: Your collection is full. Cannot add new entries.\n");
}
}

void printall()
{
int i; 

printf("\nCollections: \n"); 

for(i = 0; i < tail; i++)
{
    printf("\nVideo Name: %s", Collection[i].video_name);
    printf("\nRanking (Hits): %d", Collection[i].ranking);
    printf("\nURL: %s", Collection[i].url);
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

I am suppose to write the code that will store the collection into a file and the likewise right the code that will load the file and read from it.

Thanks to a fairly helpful TA I was able to formulate the following code for each

```
void store()
{
FILE * fileName;
fileName = fopen ( "Ranking.dbm" , "wb" );
fwrite ( Collection, sizeof(struct YouTubeVideo), MAX, fileName);

fclose (fileName);
                    }
```

and

```
void read()
{
FILE *fileName;
fileName = fopen("ranking.dbm", "rb");
if (fileName != NULL){
    fread ( Collection, sizeof(struct YouTubeVideo), MAX, fileName);
}
else {
    printf("ERROR");
                        }   

                    }
```

I believe these each to function but the real problem is I don't think I quite understand how and I believe that since I dont even know how they function, I dont know how to use them in the code.

I added both methods to the given code and came up with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX 100

struct YouTubeVideo {
char video_name[1024];      // YouTube video name
int ranking;                // Number of viewer hits
char url[1024];             // YouTube URL
};

struct YouTubeVideo Collection[MAX];

int tail = 0;

//-- Forward Declaration --//
void printall();
void insertion();
void branching(char option);
void menu();
void store();
void read();


int main()
{
char ch;

read();

printf("\n\nWelcome to CSE240: YouTube Classic Hits\n");

do {
    menu();
    fpurge(stdin);            // Flush the standard input buffer
    ch = tolower(getchar()); // read a char, convert to lower case
    branching(ch);
} while (ch != 'q');

return 0;
}

void menu()
{
printf("\nMenu Options\n");
printf("------------------------------------------------------\n");
printf("i: Insert a new favorite\n");
printf("p: Review your list\n");
printf("q: Save and quit\n");
printf("\n\nPlease enter a choice (i, p, or q) ---> ");
}

void branching(char option)
{

switch(option)
{
    case 'i':
        insertion();
        break;

    case 'p':
        printall();
        break;

    case 'q':
        store();
        break;


    default:
        printf("\nError: Invalid Input.  Please try again...");
        break;
}
}

void insertion()
{
if(tail < MAX)
{
    printf("\nWhat is the name of the video? (No spaces characters allowed)\n");
    scanf("%s", Collection[tail].video_name);

    printf("\nHow many viewer hits does this video have?\n");
    scanf("%d", &Collection[tail].ranking);

    printf("\nPlease enter the URL: ");
    scanf("%s", &Collection[tail].url);

    tail++;
}
else
{
    printf("\nERROR: Your collection is full. Cannot add new entries.\n");
}
}

void printall()
{
int i;

printf("\nCollections: \n");

for(i = 0; i < tail; i++)
{
    printf("\nVideo Name: %s", Collection[i].video_name);
    printf("\nRanking (Hits): %d", Collection[i].ranking);
    printf("\nURL: %s", Collection[i].url);
    printf("\n");
}

}

void store()
{
FILE * fileName;
fileName = fopen ( "Ranking.dbm" , "wb" );
if (fileName != NULL)
    {
        fwrite ( Collection, sizeof(struct YouTubeVideo), MAX, fileName);
        fclose (fileName);
    }

else {
    perror("Following error occurred(): ");
}
                    }



void read()
{
FILE *fileName;
fileName = fopen("Ranking.dbm", "rb");
if (fileName != NULL)
    {
        fread ( Collection, sizeof(struct YouTubeVideo), MAX, fileName);
        fclose(fileName);
    }

else {
    perror("Following error occurred with fopen(): ");
                        }   

                    }
```

Now I am sure anyone who has read this has probably already face palmed themselves cause they see the problem, but I do not. The code does not create the file to write to and likewise it has nothing to read from so I cant even begin to see what is wrong with that.
 Now I am not looking for a given answer, but I would really like to know what it is I am doing incorrectly, what concepts I appear to not understand, and how I can go about fixing these. I have done a few hours of research on this already and  I realize it is elementary, but I really would like a hand in learning. Its frustrating spending hours on a topic that the professor said should only take a couple of hours to complete at most.

Comment: fflush(stdin) is not supported as near as I can recall, fyi.

Comment: What exact error message or undefined behavior are you getting?

Comment: I am not actually getting any, it just fails to create the needed file and potentially read from it.

Comment: It may sound silly, but you are writting a file named: Ranking.dbm and trying to read a file named ranking.dbm (note the R/r difference).  If you're in windows, you'll be fine, but if you are in Linux/Unix, you'll have problems.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I guess I should add that I am using Xcode in OSX.

Comment: You really need to adopt a consistent, readable indention style. This code isn't readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor: Make sure to check the return values for things like fopen, fread, fwrite etc. more often.

Mild: You've got a potential typo in the filename (some operating systems have case-sensitive file names)

Severe: read() doesn't set up a value for tail... :)

Comment: Jacob thanks for responding. I am not sure I follow the reason for setting up a value for tail. That may seem extremely stupid on my part but again I am not sure I even understand the basics of what I have written.

Comment: On my system the file is both written and read in correctly, but the problem comes up when `printall()` is called. The for loop goes from 0 until (not including) `tail`. `read()` does not change `tail`, so after loading the file it will still be 0 and nothing will be printed when you call `printall()`. Use the return value of `fread()` to figure out what `tail` should be, based off `sizeof(struct YouTubeVideo)`.

Comment: Thanks a ton Jacob I am guessing it is just something with Xcode then not creating the file. I am still trying to figure out what i need to accomplish from what you have told me but thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You really should check the return value of `fopen()` against `NULL` - if there is a problem opening the file, it will return `NULL` and set `errno`. This is probably a permissions mistake, and by checking the return value and printing the error if one is set, you'll get more information on what went wrong.

Comment: Dan if I may, how would I go about that? because in my read statement I did put `if (fileName != NULL)` is that not the same?

Comment: You did that in the `read`, you did it exactly right. You did not do it in the `store`. If there is an error, you should also check `errno`: instead of `printf("Error")`, say `perror("Following error occurred with fopen(): ")` or something like that, it will automatically append the error that occured.

Comment: Thanks Dan so would this be close to correct?                                  `void store()
{
    FILE * fileName;
    fileName = fopen ( "Ranking.dbm" , "wb" );
    if (fileName != NULL)
        {
            fwrite ( Collection, sizeof(struct YouTubeVideo), MAX, fileName);
            fclose (fileName);
        }
    
    else {
        perror("Following error occurred(): ");
    }
                        }`

Comment: That would work. Also check the other answers, as there are a few errors with your read function that you'll run into.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Dan. I am still not able to see that my code is creating a file to ever read from? I have gone through the other answers with no avail?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have a problem with the `read` function, which does not call `fclose` on the file handle (by the way, calling it `fileName` is a little misleading).

Because you leave the file open, it's entirely likely that you won't be able to overwrite it when you eventually call `store`.  You haven't output any error messages if the file cannot be opened in that function, so it's quite easy to slip under the radar...  At least until you wonder why your file date doesn't change.

Otherwise the code looks okay.  All it does is dump the entire contents of your array out of memory and read it back in again.  What you'll probably want to do is also write out the value of `tail`, since it is keeping track of how many elements you are keeping.  So with minimal code changes, do this:

```
fwrite ( &tail, sizeof(int), 1, fileName);
fwrite ( Collection, sizeof(struct YouTubeVideo), MAX, fileName);
```

And of course the corresponding calls to `fread` in your `read` method.

```
fread ( &tail, sizeof(int), 1, fileName);
fread ( Collection, sizeof(struct YouTubeVideo), MAX, fileName);
```

To reiterate: don't forget to close your file!!!!

```
fclose(fileName);
```

Comment: okay so if I am understanding correctly I need to add `fclose(fileName)` after `fread` as I did after `fwrite` in my store function?

Comment: also when I added the changes to `fwrite` and `fread` like you posted it filled my entire collection with nonsense and printed it?

Comment: when I remove `fread ( &tail, sizeof(int), 1, fileName);` this problem goes away. But I still have not been able to create a file?

Comment: Yeah, since you wrote the file before you changed the format, if you read it in again it will contain rubbish.  You need to either translate it or replace it.  Writing it at the end of the file might be better in that case.  And yes, you should always close a file handle before the handle drops out of scope.